# При djongo, django, второе Id генерируется само, как убрать его по умолчанию?

Tags: django, mongodb

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65ea05dbaa907e05219c0934"
  },
  "id": 6,
  "title": "asd",
  "content": "asd",
  "author": "asd",
  "category": "asd",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-03-07T20:21:52.000Z"
  }
}
```